Mount /srv to another disk
I have an Debian 12 server.
I want to mount the /srv folder to another disk.
I checked this post :
Classic : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-var-directory-to-another-partition
With 'bind' mount : https://serverfault.com/questions/429937/how-to-move-var-to-another-existing-partition
What's the best solution ?
Regards.

Do you mean "mount" (as in the title of your question), or "move" as in the links that you included?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you. I will have an app with an important storage which will store data in /srv. I just want to move /srv to another disk
